# Windows .gitconfig setting for GitExtensions editor

Tags: windows, git, editor, git-extensions, git-config

Windows 7
GitExtensions

`GitExtensions` installer automatically adds a `.gitconfig` line to instruct `git` to use the `GitExtensions editor`

My `.gitconfig` was changed by another program, and `GitExtensions` installer repair mode does not re-add the setting.

Could someone please supply it ?

I've tried the following syntax but it's wrong :

```
[core]
editor =  !\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\GitExtensions\\GitExtensions.exe\"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you should set something more appropriate...

For example:

```
    editor = \"C:/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe\" -multiInst -nosession
```

For Gitextensions Editor, the path you want should be something like:

```
    editor = \"C:/Program Files (x86)/GitExtensions/GitExtensions.exe\" fileeditor
```

Comment: by "appropriate" are you implying that GitExtensions editor is not ?

Comment: Forget what I said. Even if I am a long time user and contributor and really appreciate GitExtensions, I didn't know that there was an editor. I don't know what it worth but git features needed for an editor are not very high so it should be enough good... I made that statement before knowing and didn't change it enough well.

Comment: `GitExtensions editor` is not full-featured to be sure, but actually seems more suited to its simple purpose than vim emacs etc.